# Какие макросы опредлены при релиз-сборке?

Tags: c++

Определены ли макросы:

```
__FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
```

при релиз-сборке?

**UPD** 
Компилятор GCCv4.4.3, IDE QtCreator

Comment: @ASten, Для корректного ответа уточните, версию компилятора, а также версию среды разработки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Standard Predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)
- [Function Names as Strings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Да, макросы определены независимо от типа сборки. Проверить можно просто, добавив вызов вида

```
printf ("File is %s. Line is %d.", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Answer (score 2):

А попробовать? Это же абсолютно не сложно.

Но с своего опыта скажу - да, определены, так как они от типа сборки не зависят и подставляются препроцессором на начальных этапах.

Comment: Да, я попробовал, у меня работало, просто хотелось уверенности в том, что будет работать и на других машинах с другой операционной системой и, возможно, другим компилятором. Спасибо за разъяснение про препроцессор!

Comment: С другим компилятором? ну тогда есть маленький подвох. В Visual Studia не определен `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. Почитайте [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384765/whats-the-difference-between-pretty-function-function-func), думаю найдете подходящие ответы.